# get android versionName on server side

Tags: android

I want to make my app can do auto-update by comparing version name of my app, I already know how to get my app version name with `getPackageInfo.getPackageName`, but I don't know how to get app version name from server

I want to make it like this

```
String versionName = infopackage.versionName;
String serverversion = /*something to get version name from server side*/

if(versionName>serverversion)
    updateApp();
else
    //do nothing
```

how can I retrieve version name of my app on server side?

**UPDATE**

I'm not using google play, it's just local app. and if it's possible I want to get app version name on server side directly. I mean without using text file or create a table in my database

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a table in your database with appversion and appUrl to download the newly created version.Then you need a webservice to get the appVersion and appUrl.

Compare both versionName and serverversion..

```
if(versionName>serverversion)
    updateApp();
```

Answer (score 0):

- You need to keep a file on the server side and in that text file, keep a field as versin number.
- On every update of your app, update the version number in that text file.
- On the app side, read the read file from the server on app startup. Do JSON parsing to extract the verson field from the text file.
- If the extracted version number is greater than your current version, give a popup for aap update and redirect to your app in Google Play.

Comment: is there any way to get app version name on server side directly on app? I mean without using text file. And I'm not using google play, it's just local app

Comment: Your app version name must be kept somewhere on server side. From that file you need to extract it on app side. In case it already exists some where, then no need to keep text file. Just extract data from that file in the same way.